# How to apply bitwise right shift operator on binary?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

How can I perform bitwise right shift on binary?

`>>` in JS applies to integers. So, `6 >> 1` (bitwise shift right, step 1) shows 3 as result (`110 >> 1` = `011` – correct). It is nice, but... Is it possible to work with shift right operator with binary?

I need this: `110 >> 1` working correctly. This will show 55 as result and it is correct. 110 is 01101110. `01101110 >> 1 = 00110111`. `00110111` is 55. Correct. But I want `011` as result! How I can do this in js?

Comment: Divide the number by 10?

Comment: Also, why do you want this?

Comment: Obvious problem: that's not binary. That's decimal with only the digits 1 and 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like string manipulation to me. How about:

```
function shr(x, s) {
    return
        new String('0', Math.min(s, x.length)) +
        x.substr(0, Math.max(0, x.length - s));
}

>>> shr('110', 1)
'011'
```

Alternatively, you can use the usual bitwise operators and simply convert from a string representation beforehand (once), and convert back to a string representation afterwards (once).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
(parseInt("110",2) >> 1).toString(2)      // gives "11"
```

`parseInt` can take a `radix` as a parameter, so if you pass it `2` it will treat the string as binary. So you convert to a number, shift it and then use `toString` (which conveniently also will take a `radix` as a parameter) to convert back to a binary string.